# Why RemoteViewsFactory method getViewAt work wrong but not always?

Tags: android, widget, scroll, adapter

Sometimes when my widget is updating I see in log that:

> ..
>
> getViewAt position = 7
>
> getViewAt position = 7
> ..

And at first time RemoteViews object is placed on position 0 at second time on position 7. Why this is happening? Why it call object with id 7 but place it on position 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: in ListView you can`t set height wrap_context because view do not know what is it if you have 10, 20, 100 or more elements.